# Accessing heroku private space database over AWS VPC peering connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, heroku-postgres, aws-vpc

I've successfully setup VPC peering from my AWS VPC to my heroku private space, and configured the routing from the VPC for the heroku private space CIDR. However I'm now a bit stuck trying to connect to the private space postgres database.

I think what I need, is to find the private IP address for the heroku postgres database.

Does anyone know how this is done? The only address I can find is the public IP address, which won't work because it would be routed over the internet, rather than the peering connection.

Comment: Is your questiom not answered at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-and-private-spaces?

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation about how to access the database over a peered private connection. All of the examples I've seen  use of the DNS name, which resolves to a public address.

Comment: *"Heroku Postgres in Private Spaces is only available in Heroku Enterprise."*  Are you using Heroku Enterprise?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, it's a Heroku Enterprise account.

Comment: How about using [`$ heroku pg:info`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-heroku-postgres-databases-to-private-spaces)?  If you get a public IP there, then I wonder whether your db is actually in the private space.

Comment: Open a support ticket - we've got something that can probably help here.

Answer (score 0):

The peering [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-space-peering#additional-considerations-and-limitations) states:

> You cannot connect directly to data services such as Postgres, Kafka or Redis in the private space from the peered VPC.

So it is not possible to do what you are trying to do. You can instead try using a PrivateLink to connect to a Heroku postgres instance from your AWS VPC. More details here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-via-privatelink

Comment: We've actually long since abandoned Heroku. However this could be useful for others.